# tree nodes with sequence of natural number as prefix in extjs

Tags: extjs, dynamic, sequence, prefix, treenode

I have been looking for a way to represent tree node with natural sequence number as prefix of the text dynamically.As the system has dynamic add/update/delete, so number should automatically alter.
For eq: if a node has 3 children as item1, item2 & item3.It should appear in the tree as 
1.item1
2.item2
3.item3

Also if item1 has child as item1 child1, item1 child2, the o/p would be like

1.item1
    1.1.item1 child1
    1.2.item1 child2
2.item2
3.item3

Provided that each item and subitem is being dynamically added/deleted/edited(all done)

Hope to get some response soon.
Any kind of assistance would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `renderer` of the column. Then you can calculate the text you like out of the `index` and the `text` properties of the record.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But I am using Ext.tree.Panel not treecolumn
more or less like
http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-reorder